# Issue with color animate jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, jquery-color

I am not quite sure what the problem is here. I have included the jQuery UI so that I have color compatibility.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.js"></script>
```

I have also tried before with the jQuery color plugin.

I want to change the font color but my code doesn't seem to be working. I added the backgroundColor to test it and that works.

Please let me know if you have any ideas why it isn't working.

```
$('.menu-item').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  }, 500, function(     
  ) {
  });
});

$('.menu-item').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    color: '#fff',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  }, 500, function(
  ) {
  });
});
```

Comment: If you don't have to support IE9- for this, just use transitions

Comment: Seems fine to me  http://jsfiddle.net/hAw5z/  You are animating to white both times though, so it only animates the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I needed to change the target to '.menu-item' to '.menu-item a'

Once I added the 'a' and changed the font color, it worked perfectly.

Thanks Explosion Pills and James Montagne. Also I am going to use that website you linked to James.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because on `mouseleave` you are not setting font colour back to black so it goes invisible
Try this it is working.

```
$('div').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).animate({
  color: '#fff',
  backgroundColor: '#000000',
}, 500, function(     
    ) {
   });
});

$('div').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).animate({
  color: '#000',
  backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
}, 500, function(
  ) {
  });
});
```

[check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hAw5z/1/)